# How to give arguments to kill via pipe

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, command-line-arguments

I need to search for a certain process and kill that process. I wrote a command like this:

```
ps -e | grep dmn | awk '{print $1}' | kill
```

Where the process name is `dmn`. But it is not working. How can I find processes by name and `kill` them.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

```
kill $(ps -e | awk '/dmn/ {print $1}')
```

Comment: Use the newer `$()` syntax: `kill $(ps -e | grep dmn | awk '{print $1}')`.

Comment: fwiw for others, i had to modify this answer to get it to work: `kill $(ps -efw | grep dmn | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}')` not sure why and dont care enough too look further into it.

Comment: @joshweir It is because otherwise `kill` tried to kill even the 'grep' process which was trying to search for the pattern

Comment: Wouldn't it be required `\n` after each awk, like in `awk '{print $1"\n"}'` ?

Comment: As always, [avoid the useless `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep); `kill $(ps -e | awk '/dmn/ { print $1 }'` (though of course, also, don't reinvent the wheel: `pkill dmn`).

Answer (score 59):

In case there are multiple processes that you want to remove you can use this:

```
ps -efw | grep dmn | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

Note: You need to remove grep process itself from the output, that's why `grep -v grep` is used.

Comment: You can avoid grep from showing up in your grep by putting the first char inside brackets, like: grep [d]mn

Comment: @Oldskool Nice trick. Using metacharacteres to make the grep regular expression don't match itself is a nice idea.

Comment: Nice trick, though it does make it more complicated to turn into a shell script

Comment: `kill: (15142): Operation not permitted` even adding sudo before kill

Answer (score 23):

You could use

```
pkill dmn
```

if your system has the [pkill command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkill).

Comment: +1 for pkill instead of killall. It's available on multiple platforms without different "meaning" ([killall](http://bama.ua.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?killall) on Solaris is equivalent to [killall5](http://linux.die.net/man/8/killall5) on Linux for example - That is, kill *ALL* processes)

Answer (score 5):

Just adding on others, but I like using awk's regex features capacity:

```
kill $(ps | awk '/dmn/{print $1}')
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have the `pidof` command on your system ( I know shells such as ZSH come with this by default, unless I'm mistaken), you could do something like.

```
kill -9 $(pidof dmn)
```

Answer (score 5):

You might not need `pipe` for this, if you have `pidof` command and know the image name, I did it like this:

```
kill $(pidof synergyc)
```

`$()` I understand this as it converts that output to a variable that kill can use, essentially like pipe would do. Shorter and easier to understand than some other options but also maybe less flexible and more direct.

Answer (score 3):

```
for procid in $(ps -aux | grep "some search" | awk '{print $2}'); do kill -9 $procid; done
```

hello friends .. we can do it using for loop .

"Some search"   is here any process name you want to search, for example "java" so let say count of java process is 200+ so killing one by one will be too typical .

so you can use above command.

Thanks.

Comment: The best solution for a case when search result may be empty

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [killall](http://linux.die.net/man/1/killall):

```
killall dmn
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `pgrep` with -f option.
`kill $(pgrep -f dmn)`

Comment: If you have `pgrep`, why not just `pkill -f dmn`?