# Killing subprocess started insinde new terminal

Tags: java, linux, process, subprocess, rfcomm

I have java program that spawns a new subprocess which itself executes a command in a new terminal window:

`Process proc =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("lxterminal -e sudo rfcomm watch " + BLUETOOTH_CHANNEL);`.

`rfcomm watch *CHANNEL*` watches the declared channel/linux device file for incoming data via bluetooth in my case. When the connection is canceled, I want to be able to restore it later in the program on the same device file. Since `rfcomm watch` blocks the declared device file it has to be closed before the same command runs again. This can manually by achieved by sending SIGTERM to the process (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> inside the newly spawned terminal window).

My problem is that when I do `proc.destroy()` or `proc.destroyForcibly()` it seems like only the terminal is killed and `rfcomm watch` is still running (which results in an error message when trying to watch the same device file again). `rfcomm watch` also still appears under `ps`.

How do I kill both the new terminal window **and** the command running inside it programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution/workaround which fits my purpose but might not be suitable for problems that are akin.

Since I want to kill the process that blocks the rfcomm channel I declared **and** don't use other channels **and** do not care if anything else rfcomm-related gets killed, I simply run the line `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo pkill rfcomm");` in a shutdown-hook. This works for me.

If it is important to kill only one specific process, something like this can be done: [How to give arguments to kill via pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653921/how-to-give-arguments-to-kill-via-pipe)