# How to ensure termination of a multiprocessing Pool?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I am using a Jupyter notebook to launch all manner of nonsense out of a `multiprocessing.Pool`.  Unfortunately, sometimes my workers have errors, and I need to close the pool, and start over again.

So, I have a cell that has the line `pool.close()`.  I then respawn a new pool: `pool = Pool(n, maxtasksperchild=1)`, and proceed along my merry way.

However, `.close()`ing the pool didn't do what I thought it did, and I now have a gazillion zombies on my machine.  Worse, I overwrote the `pool` variable so I have no way to close them except by manually issuing `kill` commands.  Worse still, when I issue a `kill` command for one of the zombies, a new one pops up in its place, causing me to suspect that `pool.close()` didn't, in fact, close the pool, the pool is still there, hidden somewhere, continuing even in death to execute its `map_async` command that will take 2 forevers to terminate.

In other words, `pool.close()` didn't close my pool.

I'm gonna sit here and `kill` stuff for an hour.  In the meantime does anyone know how to:

`pool.kill_all_of_the_processes_really_farill_this_time_and_prevent_them_from_ever_popping_back_up_under_any_circumstances_ever()`

---

Here's a working example:

**Cell 1**

```
import multiprocessing as mp
def work(i):
    import time
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.01)
```

**Cell2**

```
try: 
    pool.close()
except: 
    pass
pool = mp.Pool(8, maxtasksperchild=1)
pool.map_async(work, range(10000000))
```

Rerun Cell2, and `ps aux | grep python | wc -l` to see that the number of processes open increases by 8

Comment: If anyone knows how to terminate the variable-less `pool`s that are still somehow hidden in my jupyter sesh, I'd appreciate that, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool):

> close()
>       Prevents any more tasks from being submitted to the pool. Once all the tasks have been completed the worker processes will exit.

Versus

> terminate()
>       Stops the worker processes immediately without completing outstanding work. When the pool object is garbage collected
>   terminate() will be called immediately.

So you should be using `terminate()`, if you want to actually kill all the processes and not wait for them.

Concerning your comment:
You can try killing the processes with the following command (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653921/how-to-give-arguments-to-kill-via-pipe) as well):

```
kill -9 $(ps aux | grep -v grep | grep "<your search string>" | awk '{print $2}')
```

For me the path of the python interpreter was unique because i started it in a virtualenv. You could use that to filter only the jupyter python processes.

Comment: I ended up doing `kill $(ps aux --sort=start_time | grep python3 | awk '/brown     2155 /{x=NR+1000;next}(NR<=x){print}' | awk '{print $2}')` once I had killed the first few, the later ones are all "new", so this kills the "new" processes, after 2155 which I manually determined to be a good cutoff point.  They're reading from a very long queue, so hopefully the pools run out of steam eventually.  :)

Comment: This seems to have exhausted the queue, so the various open pools have stopped working hard.  However, they are still open, unfortunately.  Not sure what to do about that....